# Meteor: Difference between using PubSub and Collection.find(options) on the client

Tags: meteor

I have seen developers subscribe to data published by the server and passing in options to modify the returned cursor. I have also seen developers who just directly call `Collection.find(options)` directly from the client files.

Is there a difference between the two approaches? If so, which is the recommended method?

Answer (score 0):

Both are complementary. 
In order to fully understand how Meteor works with data you have to forget how a traditional app works (i.e. request data and get them in a static form (like json)).

**TL;DR** Do not forget that Meteor is DB everywhere

Meteor data reactivity works like this:

1) **Publication**: You have some data in your MongoDB (server) that you want to be available on the client, said last 10 articles over a total of 500. So, you will set a publication on the server like this:

```
//SERVER
Meteor.publish('lastTen', function() {
  return Articles.find({}, {limit: 10, sort: {date: -1}});
});
```

2) **Subscription**: To actually make the data available on the client you will subscribe to the publication like this on the client:

```
//CLIENT
Meteor.subscribe('lastTen');
```

3) **Fetch data on the client**: data you have subscribed to in 2) are not send statically to the client, they are instead replicated in a client side DB (currently [MiniMongo](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection)). That is why to fetch the data and display them to the user you will have to query against this DB on the client side:

```
//CLIENT
Articles.find({}, {sort: {date: 1}});
```

In this case there is no need to limit your query as you only have 10 records on the client. Also, you can sort in another order as it is a DB and not static data.

---

Be careful, by default the `autopublish` package is installed to allow fast prototyping. It will publish all the data on the client, so you don't need any publish/subscribe mechanism and it may be confusing.